# Looking for help on setting up wsl in vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I'm in my terminal and open a file with the `code` command, vscode will launch and the terminal inside code will show my full zsh setup that I have configured in hyper terminal. But if I open up code through windows, and select wsl as my default shell, it's pretty much useless. Anything I try, like sudo, git, apt, etc will return a command not found message.

So if I want to commit any changes in the terminal inside code then I have to use the git bash shell. Is it possible to get my zsh working without first launching from my terminal emulator so I'm using wsl instead of git bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running `wslconfig.exe /list` in powershell showed me that WSL was set to docker as the default shell, so then running `wslconfig.exe /setdefault "Ubuntu"` in powershell fixed my problem.